# package conflict between polyglossia and arabTeX

Tags: packages, polyglossia, incompatibility, arabtex

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{french}
 \begin{document}

 \setarab
 \fullvocalize
 \transtrue
 \arabtrue

 \RL{kw}
 \end{document}
```

When I try to compile it, i get:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \nobreakspace unavailable in encoding U.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

 l.17  \RL{kw}
```

Some Arabic sequences are impossible to write when `polyglossia` is used in the preamble with the in-understandable message about `\nobreakspace` without more explanations.

So how can I conciliate `polyglossia` with `arabtex` packages?

Comment: Check out the `arabxetex` package (by the original author of `polyglossia` or use `babel` instead of `polyglossia`.

Comment: Independently, this file produces no errors for me, so you might want to update your distribution or make sure you're not using an outdated local version of some package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that the problem only occur with `french` as main language.

So, for the moment I bypass the bugg with :

```
{\selectlanguage{english} \RL{kw}}
```

But it’s ugly and a little bit hacky…

Note that it isn’t work with `\setlanguage{arabic}`.

Comment: You really should follow Alan Munn’s advice. What you’re trying to do won’t work, because `arabtex` is only for pdftex, whereas `polyglossia` is for xetex and luatex.

Comment: I was doing that, but I use `arabtex` with XeTeX for years. Anyway, I will read the documentation and come back.